# Use of ISO-8859-2 encoding in PHPMailer

Tags: php, encoding, phpmailer, iso-8859-2

I am trying to send some Latin Extended (ISO-8859-2) characters form a LandingPage registration Form, but from $mail->Body all the "ăîâşţ" ends in the E-mail Message as "ÄƒÃ®Ã¢ÅŸÅ£".
Do I have to declare the Encoding on PHPMailer somewhere?

The awkward thing is, that all of Form data gets stored in the MySQL (INNODB-latin1_swedish_ci) with those  "ÄƒÃ®Ã¢ÅŸÅ£" character, and they parse ok "ăîâşţ", when called by the BackEnd WebPages.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, is about ISO-8859-2...

Comment: What you have is UTF-8 data being displayed as ISO8859. You need to pick an encoding and stick with it all the way, including accepting user input.

Comment: I didn't want to close it as a duplicate of "UTF8 all the way through", but that's what you should read even if you want to stick with ISO8859-2. Though, quite honestly, you're going to be best off going with UTF8 as it allows far more flexibility in what languages you can accomodate. [aka: all of them]

Comment: Thank you for the help @Sammitch. The question I have posted have no answer in the UTF-8 all the way through.